# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation on a pipeline

Tags: .net, nuget, azure-pipelines, invocationtargetexception

I've created a build pipeline for a .NET Framework project. When the pipeline is triggered by a pull request, I've got this errors on the task: 'NuGet restore'

> - ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Error parsing solution file at `d:\a\1\s\***.sln`: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  The project file could not be loaded. Could not load file or assembly `Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  `d:\a\1\s\***.sln`)
> - ##[error]Packages failed to restore

[image]

When I try to compile the solution on my local computer after merging with the target branch, I don't have any conflicts or errors.

Here is my YML file:

```yml
pool:
  name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2 # --> This task fails.
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '***.sln'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '***.sln'
    platform: 'any cpu'
    configuration: 'release'

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: ***
    ArtifactName: 'drop wa'
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be currently an issue with nuget task. You might try to change version to 5.4 as that seems to solve it for some people, including me.

Please see the link below:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/978914/nuget-restore-on-hosted-agent-builds-cannot-find-s.html

Comment: In my case, I was using *NuGet 4.4.1*. Then I set Azure DevOps pipeline agent specification to **windows-latest**. So that's why the issue started showing up. Changing NuGet to *5.4* with *Task Version* to 1.* resolved the issue for me.

Comment: @VikramSinghSaini - Can you be more specific?  I am having precisely the same issue as reported in the original post. I am somewhat new to Azure DevOps so please pardon my questions.  (1) Where and how did you go about "Changing NuGet to 5.4 with Task Version to 1*"? I am assuming this change was made somewhere within Visual Studio. Correct? (2) How did you "set Azure DevOps pipeline agent specification to windows-latest"?  I am assuming this is a setting managed within the Azure DevOps app registration for the solution.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rpowell6 **1.** No! There is no link with Visual Studio. Changes were made from Azure DevOps. [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMe1RXGwZJcwGxH1ntoGuQBbgtDa0e8z/view?usp=drivesdk). **2.** Yes! When you edit the pipeline in Azure DevOps, you get the [option](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VxMI5hutGO0MHireNFGS099p2rnZOppR/view?usp=drivesdk) to do.

Comment: @VikramSinghSaini - Thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: @VikramSinghSaini - I apologize for failing to acknowledge your response as being helpful.  Utilizing the screenshots you provided I was able to edit my Azure DevOps pipeline and make the necessary changes.  It once again works as expected. Thanks again for a very prompt and accurate response.

Comment: @rpowell6 Pleasure to help you.